# Convert two wordpress function to one

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm using the following function:

```
function shortcode_title($params = array(), $content) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'type' => ''
), $params));

return
'<div class="item js-item"><div class="header js-header">' .
($type ? " class=\"$type\"" : '') .
do_shortcode($content) .
'</div>';
}
add_shortcode('acc_title', 'shortcode_title');
```

And

```
function shortcode_content($params = array(), $content) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'type' => ''
), $params));

return
'<div class="body js-body"><div class="body__contents">' .
($type ? " class=\"$type\"" : '') .
do_shortcode($content) .
'</div> </div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('acc_content', 'shortcode_content');
```

In post editor :

```
[acc_title] Custom Title [/acc_title]<br/>
[acc_content] Custom Content [acc_content]
```

So result is :

```
Custom Title
Custom content
```

How can I change the function to get the below shortcode?

```
[acc title="Custom Title"] Custom Content [/acc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way is to add `title` as a shortcode attribute, and then concatenate the title and content before returning it.

Like this:

```
add_shortcode('acc_title', 'shortcode_title');
function shortcode_title($params = array(), $content) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'type' => '',
                'title'=> '', //added title to shortcode
            ), 
            $params
        )
    );
    //set "type" class
    $type = ($type ? " class=\"$type\"" : '');

    //concatenate outputs
    $output = '<div class="item js-item"><div class="header js-header'.$type.'">'.do_shortcode($content) .'</div></div>';
    $output .= '<div class="body js-body"><div class="body__contents'.$type.'">' .do_shortcode($content) .'</div></div>';

    return $output
}
```

This will allow you to use a shortcode like this:

```
[acc title="Custom Title" type="my-type"] Custom Content [/acc]
```